# After connect Firebase hosting to a domain, does authDomain or databaseURL in config change?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a site in production.

**After connect Firebase hosting to a domain, does config change?**

```
<pre>   
    var config = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "230086753769"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
</pre>
```

I need to know if I have to change my applications before connecting the domain. Thanks

Comment: What's with the inverted question mark though?

Answer (score 1):

No, your config will not change.  If you're using Firebase Hosting and want to use other Firebase products in your web site, it's actually easier to initialize if you use special script includes ([reserved URLs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls)) that automatically pull the correct config for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Database config does not change.
We add new domain in auth config page.